# ASP.NET refer a control from .aspx file

Tags: asp.net

I have the following code :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<body style="height: 1336px">
<input type="hidden" id="loadingtime"/>
.
.
.
.
</body>
</html>
```

and the Code.cs file is :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Diagnostics;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s = "";
        HiddenField t = (HiddenField)Page.FindControl("loadingtime");
        s = t.Value;
        Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('It took : " + s + "')</script>");
    }
}
```

I get error 
Any idea?

EDIT : 
The above problem is successfully solved by 
Now when I retrieve the value of loading time, the value is empty string. Can anyone please solve this one?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input should have runat="server" enabling it to be parsed by the ASP.NET runtime i.e.

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="loadingtime"/>
```

You can then refer to the control as you would normally in code behind using:

```
HiddenField t = (HiddenField)loadingtime;
```

AS LONG AS it is not wrapped in another server control such as an asp:repeater in which case you would need to use alternative method of traversing the control hierarchy

Comment: Exception is gone... But I am not able to get the "value" of loadingtime... I tried document.getElementById("loadingtime").value
in javascript and it works just fine. But I am not able to get this in asp.net by 
 System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputHidden t = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputHidden)Page.FindControl("loadingtime");
        s = t.Value;
        Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('It took : " + s + "')</script>");
It gives blank!!! Any idea?

Comment: @Kameron do you see the value at `s = t.Value;` ?

Comment: @ Royi Namir : I am updating my question. Please have a look.
The value of loadingtime that is retrieved is BLANK. I don't know why.

Comment: @Kameron please put your HiddenField inside `<form runat="server"></form>` tag

Comment: Worked Fine :) Thanks a lot... Just curious : Why did it not work initially?
I mean, what hapened as I put the tag inside the form tag?

Comment: the job of FORM element is to send in postback the INPUT fields to the server. those values ARE NOT stored in VIEW STATE but being sent EACH AND EACH POSTBACK. hidden field is an INPUT so its value was there but it never was sent to the server because he hasnt been under FORM element.

Comment: @Kameron Feel free to keep asking me questions.

Comment: Thank you... I got it. 
I have another requirement. How can I call a method in my .aspx.cs file as soon as the page has FINISHED loading?

Comment: you can put the code in the Page_PreRender event. or if you trully want the time when the Html is loaded , then you should use AJAX method which will be on Document.ready ( in Jquery) or window.load